# Put a build Job as failure if another job failed when the both Job are executed in parallel

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a multiJob in Jenkins with 2 phases.

[MultiJob details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgkgd.png)

I would like that if the first or the second Build Job failed, the other build Job which is in the same phase and executed in parallel is marked as failure as well.

Is that possible to do that with a condition parameter or something else ?

Here is the configuration of the multi job

[MultiJob configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa49S.png)

thanks for the help

Comment: i've not used multijob, but i doubt this is possible. what were you looking to accomplish with setting both to failed? just to make it look more obvious in the UI that it failed? i see from your first screenshot that it marked the second phase as failed when just a part of the phase failed. seems like optimal behavior to me?

Comment: Yes the phase is put as failure and it s a correct behavior for me as well. But my question was if you can put a Build Job as failure if another build Job failed (like a condition) but I doubt that it's possible too :(